# How to show that the linear operator $T$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a linear operator defined on a finite vector space $V$. Suppose that there exists a constant $\alpha>0$ so that $$\|Tv\|\ge \alpha\|v\|$$ for all non-zero vector $v\in V $. Show that T is invertible.

---

I have no idea about this proof. I try to rewrite this inequality:

$$
\|Tv\|^2=\langle Tv, Tv\rangle\ge \alpha^2\langle v, v\rangle
$$

Our goal is that show that $T^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I have fixed it.

Comment: An idea for you: if $\;T\;$  is not invertible then $\;\ker T\neq {0}\implies\; \exists\; 0\neq v\in V\;$ s.t. $\;Tv=0\;$ , and from here:

$$0=||0||=||Tv||>\alpha ||v||>0$$

and we get a contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are working in a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, $T$ being injective implies $T$ surjective, hence $T$ is bijective and invertible. So, we just need to show that $T$ is injective.

Let's suppose $T(v_{1}) = T(v_{2}).$ Then, we have $T(v_{1} - v_{2}) = 0,$ by linearity. So, we have
$$\alpha||v_{1} - v_{2}|| \leq ||T(v_{1} -v_{2})|| = 0.$$ Since $\alpha$ is strictly positive, we have $||v_{1} - v_{2}|| = 0,$ but this means $v_{1}- v_{2} = 0$, and so $T$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks. But why T being injective implies T surjective?

Comment: @Hermi Take a basis $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ for $V$. Consider $T(v_{1}), \ldots, T(v_{n}).$ A linear combination $\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}T(v_{i})$ is equal to $T(\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}v_{i}).$ If this is zero, then by injectivity $\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}v_{i} = 0$, and thus each $\alpha_{i}$ is zero. So $T(v_{1}), \ldots, T(v_{n})$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$, which has dimension $n$, so $T(v_{1}), \ldots, T(v_{n})$ must be a basis for $V$. Surjectivity follows from here.

Comment: @Termi Why asking this property "for a linear application : injective $\iff$ surjective $\iff$  bijective" which in almost every book on linear algebra ?

Comment: @JeanMarie In your comment,  after "application", are missing the words the words "on a finite dimensional linear space".

Comment: @Don Antonio You are right.